# make SECONDEXPANSION broken by implicit rule recursion?

Tags: makefile

I'd like to use .SECONDEXPANSION: as described on http://make.mad-scientist.net/secondary-expansion.  I have the following makefile:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

x.deps := y.foo

%.foo:  $$($$*.deps)
    echo $@
```

Unfortunately, when I try `make x.foo`, I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `.foo'.  Stop.
```

Running it with `-Rd`, I get

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Reading makefiles...
[...]
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `x.foo'.
 File `x.foo' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for `x.foo'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `x'.
 Trying rule prerequisite `y.foo'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `x'.
 Trying rule prerequisite `y.foo'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `y.foo'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
 No implicit rule found for `x.foo'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `x.foo'.
Must remake target `x.foo'.
make: *** No rule to make target `x.foo'.  Stop.
```

I guess it's not working because, according to the docs, "No single implicit rule can appear more than once in a chain."  But that's exactly what I need -- for x.foo to resolve to y.foo, which resolves to a rule with no dependencies.  My application demands the uniform (*.foo) naming scheme.  Can anyone suggest a work-around?  BTW, unfortunately, I must use make 3.81, not something more recent.

Comment: Since "No single implicit rule can appear more than once in a chain", how about break it with explicit rule, like `x.deps: y.foo`, `y.deps: `, then `%.foo:  %.deps`? It doesn't use secondexpansion, not sure if it's what you need.

Comment: The implicit rule you defined is being [ignored](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search) because make can't find a rule for `y.foo`, it isn't an existing file, and it isn't `.PHONY`, you'll need to make `y.foo` meet at least one of these conditions if you want the implicit rule to match.

Comment: @Eric I believe non-consecutive instances still count as the same chain.

Comment: @user657267 Why wouldn't y.foo match %.foo?  Anyway, when I add `.PHONY: %.foo` I get the same result.  Adding `.PHONY: y.foo` is not feasible since I don't know the prefixes in advance.

Comment: @theTrickster make will drop the implicit rule for `x.foo` because `y.foo` is an explicit prerequisite after secondary expansion, and therefore [isn't considered to be an intermediate file](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules). Aside from the conditions I mentioned above, `.INTERMEDIATE: y.foo` will also work. What I meant by `PHONY` was `.PHONY: y.foo`, using `%` in a phony target won't accomplish anything.

Comment: @theTrickster, did you try my suggestion? It will go thru x.foo-> x.deps -> y.foo.